# Is it possible to quantify the quality of a probability estimator?

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning, estimation

Given a number of sources of probability estimates, what is the best way to quantify the "best" source. For example, let's say I have two sources of estimates, A and B. If A says the probabilities are [.3, .5, .4, .9, .8] and B says the probabilities are [.7, .9, .5, .5, .6] and the event results are [false, false, true, true, false], how does one generally establish whether A or B was "better?"

I've been asked to clarify the specifics of the question, but my question is less about a specific solution and more that I'm interested in all the angles from which this problem is attacked.

If I were pressed into providing specifics, I'd point to a pair of thoughts I've had about this. First, when I hear people say, "I'm 30% sure that...." or, "There's only a 10% chance of that ever happening," I have wondered how you could gauge that person's skill at guessing probabilities. Clearly, I could collect a few hundred samples from that individual and see if the stuff he labels at 10% happens roughly 10% of the time, his 20s 20% of the time, 30s 30%, etc. But if the sample set is, say, a dozen different estimates covering the range from 0.0 to 1.0, how do you assess the quality of those estimates? This is a question that's been tickling the back of my mind for years.

Second, I might be writing a genetic algorithm that will look at current, highly local, weather patterns and guess the probability of the wind switching to 15-20MPH between SW and NW. I have decades of historical data, taken every few minutes, to train with, but analyzing the fitness of an individual in the gene pool hinges on that individual's accuracy in guessing probabilities.

Comment: It rather depends how you use the probabilities and the consequences of being right or wrong

Comment: I've clarified the question as much as I can, specifying that I'm interested in a specific solution, but some information on the general class of solutions where I can start, will do. The help center says that after clarification, I should add a comment asking for the hold to be removed.

Comment: There are probably a bunch of different ways to do this, but how about comparing the norms of $[0.3-0, 0.5-0, 0.4-1, 0.9-1, 0.8-0]$ and $[0.7-0, 0.9-0, 0.5-1, 0.5-1, 0.6-0]$ and declaring the smaller one "better"? You can use the Euclidean norm or whatever norm you feel works the best for your particular application.

Comment: @AlexisOlson: I think it is pretty clear from the question that you cannot choose any norm that you like, because the estimated probabilities are supposed to be correct over a large enough sample ("*I could collect a few hundred samples from that individual and see if the stuff he labels at 10% happens roughly 10% of the time, his 20s 20% of the time, 30s 30%, etc.*"). So the problem here is that we have a large number of bins and too little data for each bin, and how to combine the data across all bins to choose between guessers such that a 100% accurate guesser wins any other in the limit.

Comment: I should add that the solution would be *different* if you wanted to determine how best to use given sources with guessing history to get the best answers to new questions for which you do not know the answer. For example, a guesser who always uses a coin-flip to guess and always claims 50% confidence will be a better guesser than one who guesses right 70% of the time but always claims 100% confidence. And yet you would rather use the guesses from the second one!